# Rewrite rule with 2 variables with "/" separation

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an .htaccess file located in a folder **"/mixtapes/"** I am trying to get the URL `mydomain.com/music/downloads/mixtapes/this-title/id` to execute `mydomain.com/music/downloads/mixtapes/item.php?title=variable1&id=variable2`

I currently have the below way somewhat working but it only uses the id and I need both variables (../mixtapes/title/id)separated by **"/"** and for some reason with the below code the index page inside **"/mixtapes/"** does not work.I am stumped! I am somewhat new to this and any help is greatly appreciated!

BTW on my index page the passing url to `item.php` page is rewritten to `<a href="title/id">`I just cant seem to get it to properly execute `item.php?title=a&id=b` with the format `mixtapes/title/id`

Current htaccess file located in **"/mixtapes/"**

```
# turn mod_rewrite engine on 
RewriteEngine On

# rewrite all physical existing file or folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# allow things that are certainly necessary
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/css/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/images/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/images/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/javascript/"

# rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^mixtapes/item.php(.*) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) item.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

The comments in your .htaccess actually state wrong

```
# turn mod_rewrite engine on 
RewriteEngine On

# if requested URL is NOT a existing file  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
# or if requested URL is NOT a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# CSS, images, JavaScript are files and we will never pass this point when those are requested, next rules can be skipped

# rewrite rules
# rewrite /mixtapes/title/id to item.php?title=title&id=id
Rewrite ^mixtapes/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)  item.php?title=$1&id=$2   [L]

# catch all other requests and handle them ( optional, default would be 404 if not a physically existing file )
Rewrite (.*) index.php  [L,QSA]
```

I've assumed that your id is a numeric value.
Be aware with the use of the title in php. Don't output this directly but you can use it to verify your URL and redirect wrong title/id combos